# ionic2 cards and icons not showing up

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionicons

I am not new to Ionic, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

I am trying to create a simple list of cards on a newly created project, but they don't seem to work. I tried using both the icons and the cards separately and that didn't seem to work either.

As I said, I have created a brand new project, having the standard "home-about-etc" template, and have replaced the HTML inside the home.html file with a div with cards inside. Here is the code:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider">
      I'm a Header in a Card!
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
      This is a basic Card with some text.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-divider">
      I'm a Footer in a Card!
     </div>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

Is this a common issue that is currently being under investigation, because I really don't see how I might have done anything wrong, since I have only just created this brand new project and have copy-pasted the template for cards straight from the v2 website?

**EDIT:**

Code of the **Home.ts class**:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: In your `index.html` do you still have `<ion-app></ion-app>` entry point? What does the code for the Component for the home page look like?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I still have it, yes. As I said, I haven't changed anything but the html code displaying the 'Hello to Ionic2' text with the code shown above. I have edited my post with the code inside the Component for the home page class above.

Comment: Try removing the `<ion-header>...<ion-header>` section from this template and see if anything renders. Perhaps the <ion-navbar>` needs additional configuration and may be preventing rendering.

Comment: Also try removing the attribute `padding`, just for the sake of testing what is causing this.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky removed the <ion-header> and padding but the cards are still not there :/

Answer (score 0):

try using it as this:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: right on! Was what I was looking at the v1 documentation of how to specify cards? Thanks! :)